# How to disable Clear data button in android mobile

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am used SQLite database in my application and i insert the user details in my table and show to listview control, but when i clicked clear data button in Application settings i lost my insert value,how to prevent this,any one help for me. thanks

Comment: sorry you can't do that

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Only system apps can.

Comment: You can't override the phone settings from the app.

Comment: Read this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476623/sqlite-database-deleted-when-i-clear-data-from-application

Comment: Answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531173/how-to-disable-the-clear-data-button-in-application-info-of-manage-appliaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Cant do that

But ,instead of the **clear data** , **Manage Space** will visible in the Settings Screen  To do this,add this to your application tag in the manifest file..

```
android:manageSpaceActivity="com.packagename.appname.activities.ManageSpaceActivity"
```

When you invoke that button your appr ManageSpaceActivity will be launched

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531173/how-to-disable-the-clear-data-button-in-application-info-of-manage-appliaction) for more info..

Comment: Thanks, but any OS related issue is occured in my application future?

Comment: I guess No, but this is just a replacement of the clear data :)